# react-native app crashes on release mode - IOS with SIGABRT

Tags: ios, react-native, crash, apple-m1

App run on debug mode well and no error occur. But when i archive and run to below command;

```
npx react-native run-ios --configuration=Release
```

Archive is success but app crashes at LaunchScreen. Here is the Problem Report's backtrace.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x10f9f7368 __exceptionPreprocess + 226
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x10b148baf objc_exception_throw + 48
2   MyApp                              ->  0x100f4039c RCTFormatError + 0 (RCTAssert.m:167)
3   MyApp                              ->  0x100f59d6d __28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke + 651
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x10f0cb7fb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x10f0cca3a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x10f0dc32c _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1338
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x10f0dbde4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 31
8   CoreFoundation                         0x10f9569f7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
9   CoreFoundation                         0x10f9513c6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2482
10  CoreFoundation                         0x10f950637 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
11  GraphicsServices                       0x115fcd28a GSEventRunModal + 139
12  UIKitCore                              0x11e4b1425 -[UIApplication _run] + 994
13  UIKitCore                              0x11e4b6301 UIApplicationMain + 123
14  Akıllı Karavan                         0x100e51ac0 main + 72 (main.m:8)
15  dyld_sim                               0x10a9c32bf start_sim + 10
16  dyld                                   0x20240852e start + 462
17  dyld                                   0x202403000 ???
```

Any solution ?

Comment: any solution or workaround?

Comment: unfortunately not. I continued over the old version of the repo

Comment: are you in a monorepo?